# What is the correct preposition for "a link [in/on] your profile is dead"?

Tags: prepositions

A [recent chat conversation](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/21246404#21246404) led to the following sentence:

> One of the links **in/on** your profile is dead.

I am not sure about which preposition would be the best fit for this sentence.
I feel that **on** is a better option since the hyperlink is *displayed on* the user's profile page.

(**profile** : SE user profile.)
(The answer could be something else too.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd incline toward the preposition *'on'*. That's how we describe things ***on*** the Internet or webpages. When you talk about any profile, it is on some webpage and when it comes to a webpage, we *prefer* using 'on'.

> The link *<del>in</del> on* that page is not working

The link belongs to a profile but a profile is 'on' the page. The whole entity is on the page and thus, it is common to say 'on' the page.

I can think from a different angle, a programmer's angle. Strictly in the context of **internet**, using 'in' is preferable when we have certain boundary of an object. Say, a picture on a webpage. You have 'things' ***in*** the picture but then, when it is about 'link' that redirects you somewhere, it is ***on*** the picture.

When we build a webpage, we don't decide its boundaries. So, anything could be ***on*** the webpage. On the other hand, when we develop a text-box (as we have here, the answering box on ELL), we decide the boundary (I'm seeing this as I write this answer). So, if I want to advise a programmer to have some changes for this box, I may say,

> *"Change the icons **in** the text box"*

Why? Because I see the boundary here. It is a block and anything that happens 'within' it is 'in'.

To cut it short, when it comes to 'link', 'anchor text' or anything that you can 'click', use ***'on'*** [I work with programmers all day!].

---

By the way, it's *"One of the **links**..."* [The structure `one of [something]` is followed by a plural noun].

Answer (score 5):

Either preposition will work.

Your logic here is valid:

> I feel that on is a better option since the hyperlink is displayed on the user's profile page.

but these ways of thinking about it are also valid:

*The hyperlink is a part of the profile, so it is in the profile.*

*The profile is a "container" of sorts that have a number of things.  In (or inside, within) the profile, is a hyperlink.*

So, either one could be used.